# Is there an error in PythonDecoratorLibrary - Property Definition 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I tried to use the property definition from PythonDecoratorLibrary (example 3).
=> https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Property_Definition

```
import sys
def property(function):
  keys = 'fget', 'fset', 'fdel'
  [...]
```

After additionally importing sys I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in Angle
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in property
TypeError: property() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc'
```

Line 12 is: function() because of the sys import :)

My python version is 3.4.1 on Windows.

Comment: Stated in another way just remove the property function definition since it is a built in function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: That is *one ugly way* to allow for local functions to define the 3 property functions.

The sample decorator *masks the `property` built-in*, but then tries to use it still to produce the `property` object. Oops.

You can still access the orginal built-in with:

```
import builtins

def property(function):
    keys = 'fget', 'fset', 'fdel'
    func_locals = {'doc':function.__doc__}
    def probe_func(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'return':
            locals = frame.f_locals
            func_locals.update(dict((k, locals.get(k)) for k in keys))
            sys.settrace(None)
        return probe_func
    sys.settrace(probe_func)
    function()
    return builtins.property(**func_locals)
```

The [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) lets you access the builtins even when a local name has overridden it.

I've updated the wiki page to reflect this.

Comment: What other way(s) would you advice to use to implement a property in python3? I don't consider PythonDecoratorLibrary (example 1) and the builtin property decorator as very nice ways :)

Comment: @Paebbels: just sticking with the [`property` decorator syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (e.g. `@property`, then `@foo.setter`, etc.); in the long run, using the widespread best practice is going to lead to more maintainable and readable code, as you don't have to keep re-learning whatever alternative method you thought more readable at the time of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The example is relying on the built-in `property` function, while also naming itself `property`:

```
def property(function):
    keys = 'fget', 'fset', 'fdel'
    func_locals = {'doc':function.__doc__}
    def probe_func(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'return':
            locals = frame.f_locals
            func_locals.update(dict((k, locals.get(k)) for k in keys))
            sys.settrace(None)
        return probe_func
    sys.settrace(probe_func)
    function()
    return property(**func_locals)  # This is supposed to be the built-in property
```

So it ends up calling itself (which doesn't take a `doc` keyword argument), instead of the built-in `property` (which takes a `doc` keyword argument). So yes, the example is broken. The function it's calling `property` should be named something else, or it should save a reference to the built-in `property` and call that internally.

**Edit:** Using `builtins.property` is obviously much nicer than saving a reference to `property` before masking it. So go with that.